# javascript, how to get the same date regardless which timezone you are in?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am using kendo datepicker.  I want user to pick a date. I will save it in the database.

here's the problem.

when user in india picks "1/1/2011".  the value I get back from  kendo datepicker is

```
LOG: investmentStartDate: Sat Jan 1 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2011
```

after I save it to the database, the date changed to "2010-12-31".  I think that happens because of the timezhone, both my application server and database server are eastern time.

my users can  come from anywhere, japan, china, india or london.  is there a way i can convert this time to  the actual date regardless which timezone they live in.

Comment: looks like you need to store the dates in utc and convert to local when you access them

Comment: Are you storing in a server side database? If so, it's probably best to handle this on the server side. Nearly every server side language/framework has support for converting time between timezones.

Comment: I dont think converting to UTC will work., the example I used in my post, after converting to UTC time, it will be 2010-12-31, but i want to keep it as 2011-1-1

Comment: HTML5 has an input type for date without time zone.  I imagine Kendo would be able to use or imitate that.  If not, you can always convert the datetime+tz to a date without time zone on the server side (instead of converting to the server's time zone).

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem - I am experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Give us a little more info about your server side. I had quite some experience and trouble with timezones and kendo the other day. I managed to overcome it, so maybe I can help.

The general best practice I followed and most people like is to keep your server data in UTC timezone format, and then add the timezone difference on the client side.

The way it works for me is I pull in a DateTime from my server which is in UTC via a REST service. I have an event that fires after the datasource reads the time from the server on the clientside, the event logic finds out the browsers timezone and adds the difference to the UTC time. The user can then pick the time which is shown in his timezone. When he clicks the save button, before sending the changed data to the server, it once again gets converted the UTC timezone and is being sent to the server in that format.